# Running mpi4py script without mpi

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

Normally I'd use mpiexec to run a process on multiple hosts like:

`mpiexec -n 8 --hostfile hosts.txt python my_mpi_script.py`

where my_mpi_script.py depends on mpi4py.

Supposing I couldn't run `mpiexec` or `mpirun`, how would I be able to run my_mpi_script.py on multiple hosts -- would this be possible by changing my script or execution environment?

Edit: I'm working with a system that runs the same command on many hosts. Normally, processes would discover each other on the local network rather than all be spawned by MPI. My current solution involves: checking which host I'm on and running mpiexec on exactly one of the hosts. This doesn't work well due to some networking limitations.

Thanks.

Comment: Basically, **you don't**. Why? Most likely there is a better solution to your problem, but we can't help you if you don't tell us. The question right now is close to *I want to drive my car around a corner without using the steering wheel*.

Comment: Understood. Updated the question. I think there is a better solution, but it's not ideal, and I was wondering if there were tenable alternatives.

Comment: Within your app, you can `MPI_Comm_spawn()` on specific hosts. That being said, that looks a bit too convoluted.